# Prove that a subset is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a topological space $(X, T)$. Prove that if $A$ is a closed subset of $Y$ and $Y$ is a closed subset in $X$ then $A$ is a closed subset of $X$

My attempt:
Since $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, the open sets are of the form $Y\cap U$ with $U\in T$ and 
$Y$ is closed in $X$ implies that $X-Y$ is open and 
$A$ is closed in $Y$ implies $Y-A$ is open.

I am really stuck at this point. Can someone please help.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I just had a question in the proof: How can we be sure that every finite intersection of closed set is closed?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The closed subsets of $Y$ are of the form $C\cap Y$ where $C$ is closed in $X.$